# ValueError: too many values to unpack in a list

Tags: python

In python I have a list like below

```
in_list =[u'test_1,testing_1', u'test_2,testing_2', u'test_3,testing_3']
```

I want to print the values in this list in a loop

```
for test, testing in input:
    print test, testing
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What is the correct method?

Comment: Can you share the output you're trying to get?

Comment: What do you expect `for test, testing in input:` to do exactly?

Comment: @Mureinik I want to get `test_1, testing_1` 'test_2, testing_2` `test_3, testing_3`

Comment: @roganjosh I want the output be like `test_1, testing_1` `test_2, testing_2` test_3, testing_3

Comment: [You should switch to Python 3.6+ while yu are still learning](https://pythonclock.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of three values on the right side; you have only two variables on the left.  Doing this assignment of a sequence (list, in your case) to a series of variables is called "unpacking".  You *must* have a 1:1 correspondence between values and variables for this to work.

I think what you're trying to do is to iterate through comma-separated value pairs.  Try something like the code below.  Iterate through the three strings in your input list (use a different variable name: **input** is a built-in function).  For each string, split it at the comma.  This gives you a list of two values ... and **those** you can unpack.

```
for pair in input_list:    # "input" is a built-in function; use a different name
    test, testing = pair.split(',')
    # continue with your coding
```

Comment: `...You must have a 1:1 correspondence...` - unless you use Python v3.x which provides [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).